# What are the reference-counting rules for reinterpret_cast from raw pointers to hatted ones?

Tags: casting, c++-cx, reference-counting

If I use a `reinterpret_cast` to convert from `IInspectable*` to `Object^`, am I still responsible for releasing the original `IInspectable*`?

Clearly the produced `Object^` will release itself when it goes out of scope, so the real question is whether the reinterpret_cast implies an AddRef that gives the `Object^` a reference count of its own, or it takes ownership of the reference I already have.

There seems to be arguments to expect either way: On one hand, a COM operation should never take over the reference counts of its input pointers -- on the other hand, the name `reinterpret_cast` suggests that it just *reinterprets* my bits from "raw ABI pointer" to "hatted pointer that *already* owns a reference to the object", and it would be my job to ensure that this makes sense).

Answer (score 3):

A `reinterpret_cast<Object^>(iinsp)` call itself will have no side-effects related to refcounting, however, assigning the result of that cast to an `Object^` variable will cause an addref to occur on the object pointed to by the original IInspectable.  When that `Object^` variable goes out of scope or is assigned to null, a `Release()` will likewise be called on the underlying object.  Whether that causes the object to go out of scope or not will depend on it's internal refcount prior to this whole business.  Eg:

```
void foo(IInspectable* p) {  //assume: this comes in with a single refcount
  p->AddRef(); // refcount now 2
  reinterpret_cast<Object^>(p); //refcount still 2
  {
    Object^ o = reinterpret_cast<Object^>(p); //refcount now 3
  } //o goes out of scope, refcount now 2

  p->Release(); // refcount now 1
} //refcount is still 1, the caller of function foo is responsible for cleaning him up
```

Comment: That makes good sense, in aggregate. I'm still confused about how to understand this at the language-lawyer level, though -- plainly the evaluation of the `reinterpret_cast` _expression_ will result in _something_; what kind of thing is that? I assumed that this "something" was an _anonymous_ but otherwise fully-functional `Object^`, which had its own reference count and would go out of existence -- and therefore release its refcount -- after the enclosing assignment expression is executed (or, when the reinterpret_cast appears in a void context, immediately).

Comment: In general, I think of reinterpret_cast as being fairly "dumb".  It simply forces the compiler to take the raw pointer value, ignore the source type, and make it believe it is the destination type, even when those two types are unrelated.  This is dangerous in the general case, but okay in this particular case (IInspectable <-> Object^) because those types have the same layout.

Comment: Adding a refcount due to a cast seems unnecessary; if the temporary will only exist until the end of the expression, then why does it need an additional refcount/release cycle?  If the compiler did behave this way, I think I would think it would be a bug.